# How to get IRandomAccessStream from StorageFile

Tags: c#, uwp

First I declared

```
private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;
StorageFile capturedPhoto;
IRandomAccessStream imageStream;
```

Second I am capturing

```
var lowLagCapture = await _mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateUncompressed(MediaPixelFormat.Bgra8));

var capturedPhoto = await lowLagCapture.CaptureAsync();


await lowLagCapture.FinishAsync();
```

Third I am setting the image source:

```
var softwareBitmap = capturedPhoto.Frame.SoftwareBitmap;
SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapBGRB = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGRB);

image.Source = bitmapSource;
```

How can i get imageStream? I used CaptureElement tool in xaml .

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, the question is what do you want to do with that `IRandomAccessStreem`. Below is some code I think you'll need:

```
public void HandleImageFileOperations(StorageFile file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
         //converts the StorageFile to IRandomAccessStream
         var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
         //creates the stream to an Image just in-case you want to show it
         var image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
         image.SetSource(stream);

         //creates the image into byte array just in-case you need it to store the image
         byte[] bitmapImageBytes = null;
         var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
         bitmapImageBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
         await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
         reader.ReadBytes(bitmapImageBytes);
    }
}
```