# How to load an svg image in win2d (CanvasVirtualControl) using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win2d

I'm developing an UWP app using Win2D and I want to know how to load an .svg file(present in my application) in Win2D. I don't know how to read the svg file and convert it into RandomAccessStream.

Comment: I think this might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725372/how-to-get-irandomaccessstream-from-storagefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to load an svg image in win2d (CanvasVirtualControl) using c#?

Win2D contains [`CanvasSvgDocument`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Svg_CanvasSvgDocument.htm) class that use to load svg from stream. You could StorageFile `OpenReadAsync` method to open svg file as stream then call `CanvasSvgDocument.LoadAsync` method to get svgDocument. For more please refer the the following.

```
CanvasVirtualControl canvasVirtualControl;
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    canvasVirtualControl = new CanvasVirtualControl();
    canvasVirtualControl.Width = 1486;
    canvasVirtualControl.Height = 610;
    MyCanvas.Children.Add(canvasVirtualControl);
    Canvas.SetLeft(canvasVirtualControl, 0);
    Canvas.SetTop(canvasVirtualControl, 100);
    canvasVirtualControl.RegionsInvalidated += CanvasVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated;
}

private async void CanvasVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated(CanvasVirtualControl sender, CanvasRegionsInvalidatedEventArgs args)
{
    CanvasDrawingSession drawingSession;
    Rect rect = new Rect(args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Left, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Top, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Width, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Height);
    using (drawingSession = sender.CreateDrawingSession(rect))
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/xxx.svg"));

        using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
           var svgDocument = await CanvasSvgDocument.LoadAsync(sender, stream);

            drawingSession.DrawSvg(svgDocument, sender.Size);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I worked for me. But I have one more question, how to edit the attributes in the svg file (xml format) using the stream object

Comment: Please check [`CanvasSvgDocument `](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Svg_CanvasSvgDocument.htm) document to find `FindElementById` method. you could use it to get [`CanvasSvgNamedElement`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Svg_CanvasSvgNamedElement.htm) then edit matched attribute

Comment: Hi bro, in my .svg there is no "id" attribute so how can I get the element without an id?
Below one is my .svg file and I want to change the "fill" attribute present inside <path> element.
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(.492 .27)">
    <path fill="#000000" d="M16.8477376,7.20815969 C16.8477376,6.35482636 16.1544043,5.66149302 15.3028487>
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>

Comment: Please try use `LoadElementAsync` to get element.

Comment: Yes I tried LoadElementAsync(stream) but it returns the Root element<svg> in my case

Comment: Can you share the exact solution for my condition as I stated above in my .svg. It would be much helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. You saved me a lot of time.
I found more specific answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500209/how-to-edit-svg-file-attribute-without-changing-the-original-file-in-win2d]

Comment: I am able to change the "fill" attribute to change my icon color. But how to rotate the icon (as I used path element)? I tried transform="rotate(90)" but it doesn't work?