# Is there a way to render svg files in UWP

Tags: c#, svg, uwp

I need to render complex svg files in my UWP application, but I haven't found any way to properly render a svg file from a path without using a WebView.

Is there a library which is able to do that? Moreover it would be great if it provides DataBinding.

With complex I mean every valid svg file should be able to render properly. e.g. a base64 encoded image within the svg file

Currently I use a WebView but there are a few caveats:

- kinda slow. it takes approximately a second to load. I'd expect at most 500ms (I think that's possible)
- I have to know the size of the file in advance
- there are sometimes clipping issues
- I use it inside a scroll view with the ability to zoom and sometimes something breaks and weird things happen
- I have to cover the web view with another view and forward the events to the ScrollView (not very MVVM friendly)

Comment: I do not think there is any built in way to draw svg files. But you could convert the svg to xaml with inkscape.

Comment: I think it's time to make my first public github repository which is based on the code from inkscape. I will inform you all when this happens ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to render svg files in UWP

Sure, please refer [`SvgImageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource?view=winrt-22000) document, it could used to render svg image file. You can define a SvgImageSource by using a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) that references a SVG file.

**For example**

```
<Image
    Width="24"
    Height="24"
    Stretch="Fill">
    <Image.Source>
        <SvgImageSource  
            UriSource="/Assets/AddComment.svg" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

And you could also use Win2D library to render SVG file, this related [care reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450357/7254781) that you could refer to.